# Some related table fields not displaying in ArcPad 8

Tags: arcpad, relationship-class

I have an issue that I have been struggling with and I'll try to explain without getting too confusing.  I have an AXF that is displaying only some of the fields in a related table on the default attributes page for related tables.  So here are the details, I have 6 fields in the related table and a relationship class that relates the table to the relationship class.  Here are the specifics of the relationship;  feature class is the origin, related table is the destination, relationship is composite, messages are forward, 1-M, Primary key is GlobalID (GUID) to AuditID (GUID).  The AXF is checked out from ArcMap.  When I open the AXF in ArcPad 8, and select a feature to view the related table attribute page, the list view page is only displaying 4 of the 6 fields (Inspector - text field, Pass/Fail - coded domain, contractor - coded domain, and comments - text field).  When I switch to single line view to add data, the only fields I see are Inspector, Pass/Fail and contractor.  The comments field is not displayed (even though it was displayed on the list view page).  The other fields in the table (AuditID - GUID primary key, AuditDate - date) are never displayed on either view of the attributes table.  When I first developed the related tables and relationships, everything was working as expected with related table fields displaying in ArcPad.  When I created the production version of the geodatabase and added the related tables and relationships, things are not displaying the same.  Any yes, I created the prod database the same way I create the development one.  If any one has any insight or an answer to what could be happening, I would really appreciate the help.  My client is waiting for this application and I need to get out to the customer ASAP.

Thanks.

Tim

Answer (score 1):

my first guess would be either something to do with field type, a problem with software version creation/viewing, or utf encoding.
Without knowing more about the software environment that is about as good as I can do.

Comment: Thanks for the response Brad.  I got it working.  I ended up deleting the relationship class and the table and rebuilt them and it works fine.  I'm still curious on why just started working though since I built them the exact same way both times.